# Where can I find research data that proves best practices for creating public APIs?

Tags: api-design

I need to persuade management (product management and others) that just "publicising" internal private APIs is a bad idea compared to the best practice of creating a public API candidate, use it internally and when satisfied make it public. Can anyone help me find some facts like research papers that helps me make the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any specific research since the public interface to any API is highly subjective and specifically tied to a problem domain.

The first few pages of this pdf are an ok overview of an API for a business person:
http://aarontgrogg.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/How-to-Build-API-and-why-it-matters.pdf

This blog posts section header's highlight key points that your business partners need to think about as I think you're aware already. I would search for best practices around these specific subjects as they pertain to a public API: http://gaejexperiments.wordpress.com/2010/07/01/public-api-design-factors/

- API Format Rest vs WebServices
- Response Format XML, JSON
- Service Contract Description
- Authentication Mechanism for the Consumers of the API
- Service Versioning (so you can roll out new versions of the API without blowing everyone up)
- Rate Limits (obviously, for any number of things, preventing DOS attacks, and just managing system load)
- Documentation
- Helper Libraries
- Website for the public api
- Depending on what type of API it is... A SUPPORT TEAM

This doesn't address your internal processes either.  Should your internal systems be able to evolve faster than the public api? In most cases I think the answer is yes, as your company wants to be agile with their business model and strategy.  Having 3rd parties consume your internal systems is going to force your company to make a decision of who's more important when it's time to make an update. Either your company will have to version it's internal service and hope the third party consumers upgrade in a timely fashion, or just break the integration for all the third party consumers.

At the end of the day, it might not be worth doing. You can only screw over the people using your API so many times before they stop using it. What good is it if no one uses it.

I have been in the position before where the business has wanted an API pushed out too fast and without any governance around it. It resulted in all of my time being spent supporting people who were integrating with our API, and writing code samples for them.